# Load props before using to set state in a useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to pass a user address into this Fetch Function, set the value of a state variable equal to the address, and then use that address to make an api call. But as expected, everything runs at the same time and the api call fails because it does not receive the user address.

I am relatively new to useEffect, the below is how I assume a function like this should be written, but evidently I am missing something. It does not return any errors, just a undefined value in the log statement I have below.

```
const Fetch = (props) => {
    const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;
    const [addr,setAddr] = useState([])
    const [data,setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function Get(){
            setAddr(props.useraddress)
        }
        Get();
    }, []);
  
    async function GetNFT() {
        useEffect(() => {
          axios
            .get(
              `https://flow-testnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${api_key}/getNFTs/?owner=${addr}&offset=0&limit=10`
            )
            .then(res=> {
              setData(res.data.nfts);
            })
            .catch(err=> {
              console.log(err);
            })
        },[]);
      }
      GetNFT();
      console.log(data);

return (
   <div>
    <script>{console.log('Fetch'+addr)}</script>
        {/* 
        <>
        {data.map((dat,id)=>{
        return <div key={id}>
            <FetchData NFTData={dat} />
        </div>
        })}
        </>
        */} 
   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Any reason why u can't use props.useraddress on the api call directly? When do you change the useraddress?

Comment: @mont_ I tried that earlier, yielded the same result, assuming it is because props needs to load before it is used, so it needs some kind of await I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You need a single `useEffect` that would depend on `useraddress` that you can destructure from the `props`, and make an api call that uses the `useraddress`. You don't need to store `useraddress` in the state.

```
const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

const createUrl = addr => `https://flow-testnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${api_key}/getNFTs/?owner=${addr}&offset=0&limit=10`

const Fetch = ({ useraddress }) => {
  const [addr,setAddr] = useState([])
  const [data,setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(createUrlcreateUrl(useraddress))
      .then(res=> {
        setData(res.data.nfts)
      })
      .catch(err=> {
        console.log(err)
      })
  }, [useraddress])

  console.log(data)

  return (
    // jsx
  )
}
```

Note that the `useEffect` would be triggered on component's mount, and whenever `useraddress` changes. If `useraddress` might be empty or `undefined` when the component mounts, add a condition inside that avoids the call:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!useraddress) return // skip the api call if the address is empty/undefined/null

  axios.get(createUrlcreateUrl(useraddress))
    .then(res => {
      setData(res.data.nfts)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}, [useraddress])
```